# Use Java classes in iOS 5

Tags: java, objective-c, xcode, ios5

I'm new to Xcode/Apple programing and was wondering if it is at all possible to incorporate some Java classes into an iOS application? A way to wrap/package them so that I could call its methods?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, no. You will have to rewrite it in Objective-C. I haven't come across a converter that can do it well enough to make it worth the effort, either.

Comment: Thanks guys. That's pretty much what I thought.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to wrap Java classes within an iOS app. For a start there's no JRE on iOS.